# Image over image hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div, and another div, both have images set to them ex:

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="btnPrev"></div>
```

The image is underneath the button prev. -  what i'm trying to do is to trigger hover on image, and fade in the btnPrev, but when the mouse goes on the btnPrev it fades out due to leaving the div id 'image'.

Is there a way to 'append these together', I cannot place btnPrev inside 'image'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I cannot place btnPrev inside 'image'.` However, you can create a class.

ex :

```
<div id="image" class="hoverDiv"></div>
<div id="btnPrev" class="hoverDiv"></div>
```

And then in your JQuery you can say :

```
$('.hoverDiv').on("hover", function() {

    //Do stuff

});
```

However, I do think that if you put them into one containing div it would work much better because `btnPrev` won't be showing initially so if you have :

```
<div id="imageContainer">
    <div id="image" class="hoverDiv"></div>
    <div id="btnPrev" class="hoverDiv"></div>
</div>
```

and then your JQuery function should look like :

```
$('#imageContainer').on("hover", function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating:

The image has a class too, that changes from time to time. - the btnPrev doesn't though.

Comment: @user3451555 that doesn't matter. You are allowed to have multiple classes on a single object. so you can say `class="hoverDiv thisClass thatClass changingClass"` and then use each one of those for different purposes

Comment: @user3451555 yeah, comes in handy a lot. However, keep in mind you CANNOT have multiple `id` tags. Moreover, you should really only have a specific id once on any given page. But if you need something a little more dynamic classes are easy to work with especially because you can have multiple classes

Comment: @user3451555 please don't forget to mark an answer if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap these divs:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="image"></div>
  <div id="btnPrev"></div>
</div>
```

Your CSS :hover would be on .container:

```
.container:hover #image {
    /* do something */
}
```

I realized you want to do jQuery. In that case the selector would be the same: `$('.container:hover #image')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="btnPrev"></div>
```

CSS

```
#image:hover + #btnPrev,
#btnPrev:hover{
    /* Styles here */
}
```

**Updated with fiddle** : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z3b5L/8/)